掃除機 vs. 集塵機 vs. 吸塵機
Which would be the difference between 掃除機, 集塵機 and 吸塵機 for saying "vacuum cleaner"?
I always use 掃除機, since it is the word I hear the most, but I'm interested in enriching my vocabulary, and since I see some Japanese authors use 集塵機 and 吸塵機 apart from 掃除機, I would like to understand the difference between the three words.
For example,
膨大な時の流れが一瞬、春恵の頭の中で嵐のように吹き荒れたかと思うと、まるで巨大な集塵機で吸い上げられるようにして、瞬く間に消えていった。
小池真理子『ひるの幻 よるの夢』
今日のデパートの市なんかだって、この吸塵機ていどの商品が出品されてりゃ、オンの字だったんだ。
安部公房『方舟さくら丸』

It would be unlikely to say 集塵機 or 吸塵機 to refer to a normal vacuum cleaner. They more refer to industrial devices, like a dust collector that would be used for woodworking.
集塵 is a bit more flexible than 吸塵 because it doesn’t specify the mechanism of action, so for example you can say 静電集塵機 etc.
Honestly I don’t think I’ve really come across 吸塵機 personally in practice, 吸塵 is more used as the name of a function of some other tool (like パワフル吸塵 etc).
BTW the above is more the realistic pragmatics of the words, but in novels, like the ones you quoted, much of these pragmatic considerations go out of the window because of artistic license, so sometimes novels are not the best for learning these nuances.

Thank you very much for your answer! It helped me a lot to understand better the usage and nuances between the three words.
